# Visual Studio 2010 Stops Building Randomly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I made this post over at StackOverflow and they directed me here, here is the original post I made there about this problem:

I am having a problem with Visual Studio 2010 as of late that I can't figure out. Lately after having VS2010 open for an extended period of time, building begins to fail without error. This includes build, rebuild, and clean.

The output from VS2010 is only two lines:

```
When trying build:

    1>------ Build started: Project: example, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

When trying rebuild:

    1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: example, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

When trying clean:

    1>------ Clean started: Project: example, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    ========== Clean: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The only way I can resume using VS to build the project(s) is to restart my system. However, using msbuild from the commandline builds the project(s) without issue. So this appears to be related to VS itself but I can't figure out whats causing it with no actual error being displayed.

I have tried restarting VS itself, deleting .suo, .ncb, precompiled headers, etc. to see if it is a file lock issue which did not help or fix the problem. There are no stray processes running from a previous build when this starts happening either.

Edit --8<------------------------------------------

Just for some added information:

- I have reinstalled VS2010 twice to try to correct this.
- I have reinstalled VS2010 SP1 twice along with that.
- This only happens with VS after an extended period of time.
- It seems to occur when modifying a header (C++) file for a long time.
- After it happens I can still build from the command line fine just not from VS until I restart the system.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the MSBUILD output to Verbose or Diagnostic to see the exact error.
The option would be under Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions.

Comment: I have tried this already; sorry I forgot to include the little bit of help I received from StackOverflow. However, setting the verbose level to Diagnostic doesn't change the output. It still only outputs the above errors I posted in my original post.